# External Filter on ag-grid not working

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

I don't want to use the built-in Filter on ag-grid, so I tried using External Filtering in ag-grid, without success. Can someone steer me in the right direction?

**HTML:**

```
<input class="ag-filter-filter" id="filterText" type="text" ng-   change="filterOwnerField()" ng-model="Owner" placeholder="Filter Owner" />
```

**AngularJS:**

```
function isExternalFilterPresent()
{
    return $scope.Owner != '';
}

function doesExternalFilterPass()
{
    return $scope.Owner != '';
}

$scope.filterOwnerField = function ()
{
    $scope.gridOptions.api.onFilterChanged();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the code inside `isExternalFilterPresent()` function does not make sense. Grid calls this method to know if external filter is present. Change your function as below -

```
function isExternalFilterPresent()
{
    return true;
}
```

Also, `doesExternalFilterPass()` is not used correctly. It should be like -

```
doesExternalFilterPass(node){
    if(node.data.filedToBeFiltered.matches(// Filter string)){
       return true;
    }
}
```

Refer [ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-callbacks/#gsc.tab=0) documentation for list of  filter callbacks and their uses.